# Readline function in C outputs weird results

Tags: c, linux, shell, gnu, readline

I'm trying to implement auto completion and history in my shell using the GNU Readline library. I was using `fgets()` to retrieve user and after reading on how the `readline` function works, I decide on using it so as to support auto completion etc. But when I execute my program, the `readline` function outputs weird characters on the shell before I even type any input. Weird results like `P�6`, `PJ�` `` `, ``P�#`,`P�s`. For some reason it always start with P. Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

char *historic, userInput[1000];
static char **cmdArgv;/**The argv of the main*/

sa.sa_handler = handle_signal;
sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART; /** Restart function incase it's interrupted by handler */
cmdArgv = malloc(sizeof (*cmdArgv));
welcomeScreen();//just printf's nothing special
while(TRUE)
{
    shellPrompt();// getcwd function
    historic = readline(userInput);
    if (!historic)
        break;
     //path autocompletion when tabulation hit
    rl_bind_key('\t', rl_complete);
     //adding the previous input into history
    add_history(historic);    
    if( check_syntax(userInput) == 0 ){
        createVariable(userInput);
    }

    else{
        tokenize(cmdArgv, userInput);
        special_chars(cmdArgv);
        executeCommands(cmdArgv, userInput);
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise `userInput` before passing it to `readLine()`:

```
memset(userInput, 0, sizeof(userInput));
```

This is the description for argument passed to the `readLine()` function (which I found here [man readline](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3)):

*If the argument is NULL or the empty string, no prompt is issued.*

As you had not initialised `userInput` it was displaying whatever happened to be in there.

Comment: @hjmd: Thanks it works. But why do I have to memset userInput in my case? I went through a lot of tutorials on readline and none of them did this.

Comment: @hjmd: Just saw your edited answer. Thanks. Still baffles me why no tutorial mentioned it.

Comment: The examples I see used `sprintf()` or similar to populate the argument to `readLine` which would have populated it with a null terminated string and displayed something sensible. Try populating it with something to witness the behaviour. For example, after the `memset()` call do `userInput[0] = '$';` and you should a dollar prompt displayed.

Comment: You're right, the tutorials used `sprintf()` or functions similar to it. I tried your example.... I now get it. `userInput` was only declared. So it contained random characters. So it was  displaying whatever was there. Thanks for the help :)